# On weak and weak-* topology or a normed vector space

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-topology

The Eberlein-Smulian Theorem says that sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness in the weak topology in a Banach Space.

Is this result true when one considers the weak-* topology?

I'm also wondering if weak or weak-* sequential continuity implies continuity in these spaces.

Thanks!